# rawToHex(sys_guid()) usage in h2 in memory with oracle mode

Tags: h2

I'm trying to write some tests for my java application and my entity persistence uses oracle's sys_guid() for primary key.
Everything works fine when connected to oracle, but when I use H2 in memory for my testing, the following statement used to generate the primary guid value as a char(32) returns a much bigger string (144).

```
select rawtohex(sys_guid()) from dual
```

Is there an extra configuration to correctly setup oracle mode or is this somehow a bug

I'm using springboot with spring-data and hibernate to handle database comunication, here is a sample method that generates the guid.

```java
@Repository
public interface TokenRecuperacaoSenhaRepository extends ExtendedSpringRepo<TokenRecuperacaoSenha, String>
{
    @Query(value = "select rawtohex(sys_guid()) from dual", nativeQuery = true)
    public String genereateToken();
}
```

When connected to Oracle, returns "8E0FFC48082AB39FE0539BD3E10AC537"
While with H2, returns "00660032003300620037003000360065002d0031006400630066002d0034003700620030002d0039003400360066002d006100620065003400320034006400360030006300360038"

I'm guessing there is some conversion issue with the functions used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `SYS_GUID()` and `RAWTOHEX()` functions are non-standard and aren't fully compatible between Oracle and H2.

This incompatibility was fixed in Oracle compatibility mode of H2, so if you can build H2 from its current sources you will be able to use these functions in this compatibility mode.

You can get the sources from the GitHub:
https://github.com/h2database/h2database

Building instructions are here:
https://h2database.com/html/build.html#building

You need the jar target.

Don't forget to set the compatibility mode by appending `;MODE=Oracle` to your connection URL or by using `SET MODE Oracle;` command.

If you cannot use an own build of H2 you need an alternative method for H2 that will use something like `SELECT CAST(CAST(UUID() AS BINARY) AS VARCHAR)`